# How to apply weighting to fuzzy search results

Tags: fuzzy-search, relevance

I'm writing a service which should sensibly suggest UK place names based on user entered text, my data set is just under 2500 entries. So far I'm applying a slightly modified version of the Damerau Levenshtein algorithm which ignores the edit distance for comparing against longer strings.

This is giving me a reasonable set of suggestions but I'd like to manually weight some terms e.g. currently entering `new` will give `New Mills` as the top result.

I'd like to weight these results so major cities appear above towns and villages e.g. entering `new` will give `Newcastle` as the top result.

Can anyone suggest either a different search algorithm, or a separate weighting process I can apply to my results to achieve the weighted results I'm after?

Answer (score 1):

Levenshtein is more for typos - what you want is NLP, you can google: NLP address
or see [Detect/Parse Mailing Addresses in Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099684/detect-parse-mailing-addresses-in-text)